# I am trying to create package.json, but when I am writing 'npm init' the error code shown in the image is coming. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, package.json

[image: 1]

I am trying to create package.json, but when I am typing 'npm init' in hyper.js terminal the error code in the image is coming up, I have also tried to use windows powershell but it's not working. What should I do?

Comment: Don't post your error messages as images. You can copy-paste the error from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The error (`npm/node_modules/semver/functions/valid.js` missing) indicates your NPM installation is broken (missing a file).

I would recommend uninstalling, then reinstalling your Node.js so you get a fresh copy of the NPM it bundles.